# Rank() in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to assign rank value based on count of products(eg prod 1 has count of 100 which is max should have rank 1, prod 2 the second highest count of 80 should have rank of 2 and so on ) has but when i execute below query i get an error saying - Field 'rank_' not found in table 
. Please let me know where am i going wrong

```
SELECT
  ProdName,
  NoofProds,
  rank_
FROM (
  SELECT
    ProdName,
    COUNT(ProdName) AS NoofProds,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ProdName ORDER BY NoofProds DESC) AS rank_
  FROM
    [prodtable]
  WHERE
    (STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(Timestamp,"%Y%m%d")) = (STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, "day"), "%Y%m%d"))
  GROUP BY
    1,
    3
  ORDER BY
    2 DESC)
GROUP BY
  1,
  2,
  3
ORDER BY
  rank_ DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```
SELECT
  ProdName,
  NoofProds,
  RANK() OVER(ORDER BY NoofProds DESC) AS rank_ 
FROM
(
  SELECT
    ProdName,
    COUNT(ProdName) AS NoofProds 
  FROM [prodtable]
  WHERE (STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(Timestamp,"%Y%m%d")) = (STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, "day"), "%Y%m%d"))
  GROUP BY 1
)
ORDER BY rank_ DESC
```